# Changing Indices values w.r.t the max of array after an equality check

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, max

I'm using Matab 2014a, I have 3 arrays rx, ry and rz containing correlation values, I extract the index of the max of each array like this :

```
[~, idx] = max(rx);
[~, idy] = max(ry);
[~, idz] = max(rz);
```

This 3 indices should be different, so I check the equality between these 3 inices, what I want is if `idx==idy || idx==idz || idy==idz`, how can I take the second max of rz for idz, and the same for ry and idy. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to _know_ if the values are all different? `result = idx~=idy & idy ~= idz & idz ~= idx;` or `result = all(diff([idx idy idz idx]))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I know how to check if the values are different, what I want is if [code](idx==idy || idx==idz || idy==idz), how to change idz value with extracting the second max of the rz array, and the same for idy

Comment: Well, that's by no means what your question currently says. Please rewrite to indicate that

Comment: It's done, I changed the title

Comment: That is not adequate. Please change your question to include what you want, and illustrate with an example. Show what you have tried. This is not an especially difficult problem, but if you are lazy about asking a specific question, you are not likely to receive a specific answer.

Comment: It's done, I modified the question

Comment: idx, idy, idx are the indexes where the max occurs. Do you want to check if the index are the same? or if the actual max value is the same?

Comment: Thank you, I resolved my problem
`[max_value,idx1] = max(rx);`  
`rx(idx1) = NaN;`
`idx2 = max(rx);`
`rx(idx1) = max_value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how to check the index of the max value and select the next if they are equal:

```
rx = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5];
ry = [4, 9, 3, 2, 1];
rz = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0];

[~, idx] = max(rx);
[~, idy] = max(ry);
[~, idz] = max(rz);

equal = 1; % flag
while equal
    if idx==idy
        disp(['Max index for ry is the same: ' num2str(idy)]);
        disp ('Changing ry...');
        % Remove the max value
        ry(idy) = 0;
        [~, idy] = max(ry);
        disp (['Recalculating idy for new max: ' num2str(idy)])
    end
    
    if idx==idz || idy==idz
        disp(['Max index for rz is the same: ' num2str(idz)]);
        % Remove the max value
        rz(idz) = 0;
        [~, idz] = max(rz);
        disp (['Recalculating idz for new max: ' num2str(idz)])
    end

    % Check the changes made
    if idx==idy || idx==idz || idy==idz
        equal = 1;
    else
        equal = 0;
    end
end
```

During the first iteration of the while loop you will get

> Max index for rz is the same: 1
>
> Recalculating idz for new max: 2

since both idy(4) and idx(9) (maximums) have the index 1. During the second iteration:

> Max index for rz is the same: 2
>
> Recalculating idz for new max: 3

The values of idy and idz are equal, so again idz is recalculated. After this the 3 indexes are different:

> idx = 1
> idy = 2
> idz = 3

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did